# How to load a javascript file and run a javascript method in java?

Tags: java, javascript

I'm using [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) on the client side to render markdown code to html.

But now I need to do the same thing on the server side which is Java. In order to get the exact same html code, I have to use marked other than other java markdown libraries.

How can I load the "marked.js" file in java and run the javascript code?

```
marked.parser(marked.lexer("**hello,world**"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 options:

1. Have a look at the [`Rhino`](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) [tutorial](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html).
2. Then refer to the [RunScript](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/examples/RunScript.java) example, reproduced below and embed Rhino yourself.
3. Then edit it to fit your needs

OR:

Directly use the internal ScriptEngine in Java SE 6 and later, that comes bundled with Rhino for you. See the `RunMarked` example below adapted to your needs.

---

## RunScript.java

```
/*
 * Licensed under MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0
 */

import org.mozilla.javascript.*;

/**
 * RunScript: simplest example of controlling execution of Rhino.
 *
 * Collects its arguments from the command line, executes the
 * script, and prints the result.
 *
 * @author Norris Boyd
 */
public class RunScript {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Creates and enters a Context. The Context stores information
        // about the execution environment of a script.
        Context cx = Context.enter();
        try {
            // Initialize the standard objects (Object, Function, etc.)
            // This must be done before scripts can be executed. Returns
            // a scope object that we use in later calls.
            Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

            // Collect the arguments into a single string.
            String s = "";
            for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
                s += args[i];
            }

            // Now evaluate the string we've colected.
            Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, s, "<cmd>", 1, null);

            // Convert the result to a string and print it.
            System.err.println(Context.toString(result));

        } finally {
            // Exit from the context.
            Context.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

## RunMarked.java

*Actually, I noticed [Freewind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444907/453590), and I would have written exactly the same (except I'd load the lib directly with `Files.toString(File)` using Google Guava). Please refer to his answer (and give him points if you find his answer helpful).*

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String md2html() throws ScriptException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    File functionscript = new File("public/lib/marked.js");
    Reader reader = new FileReader(functionscript);
    engine.eval(reader);

    Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;
    Object marked = engine.get("marked");
    Object lexer = invocableEngine.invokeMethod(marked, "lexer", "**hello**");
    Object result = invocableEngine.invokeMethod(marked, "parser", lexer);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 as I was going to write something similar for the 2nd part of my answer and you had already superbly done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) to run JavaScript on the server that runs java.